# Valid regex for capturing routes with id

Tags: node.js, regex, express-jwt

I am using Express-JWT to let through all routes with a given ID, that is `/api/v1/hub/track/1`, `/api/v1/hub/track/2` etc should be let through. My function is as below:

```
 return expressJwt ({ secret, isRevoked }).unless({
    path: [
        '/api/v1/hub/track/*',
    ]
})
```

My question here is that, is `/api/v1/hub/track/*` a valid Regex? If not how do i write a valid regex that can work in in my case, that is capture all routes in this format `/api/v1/hub/track/*`

Comment: It is surely a valid glob, but it is also a valid regex, though as a glob it makes sense, as a regex, no. In regex, `.*` is used to match any 0 or more chars, in glob, just `*`

Comment: Can you perhaps help me with a valid regex for that scenario?

Comment: As Wiktor stated, `/api/v1/hub/track/.*` would be a Regex equivalent to the glob.

Comment: this solution did not work for me